# If I assign instance fields in HttpServlet#init(ServletConfig), does the Servlet spec guarantee I can read them in doGet()?

Tags: java, servlets, thread-safety, specifications

The Servlet specification provides that a container will instantiate a single instance of my `java.servlet.HttpServlet`, and invoke the service methods (`doGet()`/`doPost()`) from multiple worker threads.

According to normal threading rules, it is not guaranteed that assignments to instance-level fields in `init(ServeltConfig)` 'happen before' reads from those same fields by other threads executing `doGet()`, unless *someone* arranges for synchronization at some point.

Probably, containers do in fact do some kind of external synchronization to ensure that work done in `init()` is visible to 'subsequent' threads.

However, does the Servlet spec explicitly guarantee that I'm threadsafe?  I couldn't find a guarantee like that just now, although I must admit, I haven't read the spec from end-to-end since Servlet 2.4.

EDIT

For example, since some answerers are getting things mixed up, my question is: what is it about the Servlet spec that says the following class is threadsafe?

```
@WebServlet (initParams = {@WebInitParam(name="b", value="true")})
public Decider extends HttpServlet {

    private boolean b = false;

    public void init(ServletConfig config) {
        this.b = Boolean.parseBoolean(config.getAttribute("b"));
    }

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {
        res.sendRedirect(b ? "/true" ? "/false");
    }

}
```

Certainly, if I were to do:

```
public static void main(String[] argv) {

      HttpServlet s = new Decider();

      Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            s.init(...);
        }
      });

      Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            s.doGet(...);
        }
      });

      t1.start();
      t2.start();
}
```

... then I'd have a threading bug.  What makes containers necessarily different?

EDIT 2

All the answers asserting that "the container takes care of that" are certainly welcome, but my question is specifically about whether the *Servlet spec guarantees* that behaviour.  To answer the question adequately, you've got to make reference to the Servlet spec.  (Any version, I'm cool).

Comment: Servlets are *not* thread safe.  I would avoid state in servlets like the plague.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why Servlets are not thread Safe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555842/why-servlets-are-not-thread-safe)

Comment: @duffymo, but that shouldn't prevent the OP to initialize a shared data source, for example, in the `init()` method. The question is: is it guaranteed that this shared data source is visible to threads invoking the service method. I haven't seen any explicit guarantee in the spec, but I would assume that the container is seriously buggy if it wasn't so.

Comment: I should amend my answer: Shared, read only data isn't an issue.  It's *mutable* shared state that's a problem.

Comment: @duffymo I have updated the question to show that it is not really the same question as 'Why Servlets are not thread safe'?

Comment: @JBNizet I agree that is probably safe de-facto.  I was just interested (because of my growing concurrency awareness, and seeing a bunch of worker threads for Tomcat in the debugger), that I'd never thought about the issue before now.

Comment: More likely a duplicate of  [Marking Servlet instance variables defined in init as volatile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719916/marking-servlet-instance-variables-defined-in-init-as-volatile?rq=1)

Comment: I have raised an [issue against the servlet spec](https://java.net/jira/browse/SERVLET_SPEC-81), and we will see if they feel it is worthwhile clarifying the situation.

Answer (score 7):

This is explicitly said in the `init` [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Servlet.html#init%28javax.servlet.ServletConfig%29):

> The servlet container calls the init method exactly once after
>   instantiating the servlet. The init method must complete successfully
>   before the servlet can receive any requests.

And if you follow servlet life cycle, it says that a servlet should be `init`-ed before `service` requests from multiple threads.

Comment: To complete your answer : if i remember right, there was a SingleThreadModel (http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/SingleThreadModel.html) marker interface in earlier servlet specs. Container guaranteed that requests will be sent one by one (not parallel) to the Servlet which implemented that interface. But i really not sure if latest specs have some equivalent.

Comment: That's good so far as it goes, but `init()` will be called from some thread at webapp startup, and `doGet()` will be called from any other thread in the server's threadpool.  Who is responsible for arranging for safe publication of field values?

Comment: @DavidBullock I think there is an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719916/marking-servlet-instance-variables-defined-in-init-as-volatile . So you could assume that it is true by how `GenericServlet` is implemented.

Comment: @DavidBullock From spec point of view I think that `complete successfully *before*` could be understand as formal `happens-before` relationship.

Answer (score 2):

> ... then I'd have a threading bug. What makes containers necessarily
>   different?

In your example, the `init()` and `doGet()` methods can overlap. This is not possible in a `Servlet` container. The container takes care to do all `init()` calls and other initializations before it starts handling requests. There's no issue of multithreading across those method boundaries.

You'll still have issues with shared date being used in the `doXXX()` methods.

Short of looking at the source code of each container, your best bet is to see the [javadoc for `Servlet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/Servlet.html) (and `Filter`):

> This interface defines methods to initialize a servlet, to service
>   requests, and to remove a servlet from the server. These are known as
>   life-cycle methods and are called in the following sequence:
>
> - The servlet is constructed, then initialized with the init method.
> - Any calls from clients to the service method are handled.
> - The servlet is taken out of service, then destroyed with the destroy method, then
>     garbage collected and finalized.

To truly support the `Servlet` spec, the container has to follow those rules.

This `Servlet Life Cycle`  is described in chapter 2.3 of the [Servlet 3.0 specification document.](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/)

> **After the servlet object is instantiated, the container must
>   initialize the servlet before  it can handle requests from clients.**
>   Initialization is provided so that a servlet can  read persistent
>   configuration data, initialize costly resources (such as JDBC™
>   APIbased connections), and perform other one-time activities. **The
>   container initializes  the servlet instance by calling the `init` method
>   of the Servlet interface** with a  unique (per servlet declaration)
>   object implementing the ServletConfig interface.

Important parts in **bold**.

Comment: Just need to point out where the specification imposes this behaviour on containers, and you've got a correct answer :-)

Comment: @DavidBullock The Servlet spec is the best you're going to get. Added link in my answer.